# String index out of range (odoo 15)

Tags: string, index-error, odoo-15

I have done this code, but when running its telling me that the string index is out of range, any help is appreciated

purchase_agreement_id=fields.Many2one('purchase.requisition', string='Purchase Agreement Id')

```
def purchase_agreement(self):
    for rec in self.env['purchase.requisition'].search(['id', '=', 'purchase_agreement_id']):
        lines = []
        if rec.purchase_agreement_id:
            for line in rec.purchase_agreement_id.line_ids:
                vals = {
                    'product_id': line.id,
                    'description': line.product_description_variants,
                    'quantity': line.product_qty,
                }

                lines.append((0, 0, vals))
            rec.line_ids = lines
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrong search syntax.

It should have a list of tuples. And on the right hand side, it must contain the field's value.

And you do not need to find a record set for the `many2one` field. We can access field value directly.

Try with following:

```
for rec in self:
    lines = []
    x
    x
    x
```

For more about search domain, you can refer Odoo documentation [search method](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/reference/backend/orm.html?#odoo.models.Model.search)